# Flip Container View inside View Controller on Uibutton Pressed

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uicontainerview

I have a View controller in which I have one Table View and one Conatiner View. How can I make them flip on button pressed?

Comment: Please read [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post with more information, sample code, and the steps you have taken so far. This information will make it more likely that someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using the following command

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
```

NOTE: this will flip all the images and text inside your view so you will have to iterate them all and flip all of them individually to make it displayed properly.

Comment: I can provide more guidance once more clear requirements are given.